# How to package other packages python

Tags: python, package

Here for example, I use numpy and tkinter in my program.

When I package my small program, how can I include numpy and tkinter, so that for the people who doesn't have a python, can run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [py2exe](http://sebsauvage.net/python/snyppets/index.html#py2exe).

This will help you to convert your py code to exe application and also packages the required libraries.